# Probe instead of nozzle centres on the bed

Tags: marlin, troubleshooting, bed-leveling, tronxy-x5sa

Problem is that the probe is in the center of bed instead of the nozzle. How fix it on my Tronxy X5SA?

Those are my current settings and the nozzle is shifted from the centre (X: 35 mm, Y: 3 mm):

```
#define NOZZLE_TO_PROBE_OFFSET { -37, 3, 0 }
#define Z_SAFE_HOMING
```

(Marlin 2.0 configuration)

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem? Are you looking for solution of something, or just explanation (@0scar just provided)? Do you experience any leveling issues because of this? Btw. If the probe is in the center during leveling, or the probe is in the center after homing (for example) and that's why you are concerned?

Comment: I've seen the edit, what is there to fix? Are you referring to the difference between 35 en 37 mm?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** You don't need to fix it, it is by design.

---

When using a probe, defined the correct probe X (`xxx`) and Y (`yyy`) offsets (`#define NOZZLE_TO_PROBE_OFFSET { xxx, yyy, 0 }`) and having enabled `#define Z_SAFE_HOMING` will cause the probe to home in the middle. That is how it is supposed to work!

If the nozzle would be in the center, then you wouldn't probe the middle of the bed, but the offset from the nozzle.

Comment: Thist is a problem because printer defines that point as center of the bed so printings are not centered, sfifted -37, 3.